# Generating C++ constructors and destructors with Eclipse UML plug-in Papyrus

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, destructor, papyrus

Our goal is to use the C++ code generator from Papyrus. One problem is that the stereotype for C++ constructors and destructors does not exist.
I saw that a Java constructor stereotype exists, is there something similar for C++? If not, how could i create one by myself?

Tl;DR:
How can a C++ constructor/destructor be created in the Papyrus designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to the Eclipse forums.

Papyrus designer queries whether the stereotypes "Create" and "Destroy" from the UML standard profile are applied to an operation. This profile is available via the "apply registered profile" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I used the basic C++ generator for an embedded project (AVR) which supports C++ classes.

I used a normal function which returned a primitive type called 'NoReturnType' which I had defined.

In the code, I had a
`#define NoReturnType`

which removes it at compile time.

Vincent